# unique model background color for dialog jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How do I change the model background color for

```
$dialog1 modal background to red 

$dialog2 modal background to blue
```

I do not want a global solution  I need to change each to be unique.

Thanks for the help

http://jsfiddle.net/wMmmX/

```
    var $dialog1 = $('<div />');
    $dialog1.dialog({
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        position: [0, 0] ,
        open: function () {
            //$('.ui-widget-overlay').css({ 'background': 'red' });
            $(this).css({ 'background': 'red' }); // not changing modal back ground
        }
    });

    var $dialog2 = $('<div />');
    $dialog2.dialog({
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        position: [200, 200],
        open: function () {
            //$('.ui-widget-overlay').css({ 'background': 'blue' });
            $(this).css({ 'background': 'blue' }); // not changing modal back ground
        }

    });
```

Comment: can you be more specific what do you mean by `background color` here i mean do you want to change that  grey theme of dialog by changing color scheme of all the parts including header, body etc of dialog?

Comment: hi yes - change the grey to red and blue  . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one :

```
var $dialog1 = $('<div />');
$dialog1.dialog({
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    position: [0, 0] ,
    open: function () {
        $(this).dialog('widget').next('.ui-widget-overlay').css({ 'background': 'red' }); // not changing modal back ground
    }
});
```